# Is $X$ path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be union of lines $\{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and the origin. Is $X$ path-connected?

Attempt: My claim is that this is not path-connected by showing that there is no path from the origin to any other points of $X$. It seems to me that we can do this by contradiction by showing that the image of any path would be a disconnected subspace of $X$, similar to the proof that the topologist's sine curve is not path-connected. But all of these are just ideas and I don't know how to proceed. This is a practice qualifying exam problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think a path $(1,1) \to (1/2, 1) \to (1/2, 1/2) \to (1/3, 1/2) \to (1/3, 1/3) \to \cdots$, "parametrized by arc length," would have limit $(0,0)$ as $t \to 2^-$ and thus give a continuous path from $(1,1)$ to $(0,0)$.

Comment: It is not locally path connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is path connected. Let's now construct a path from $(1,1)$ to $(0,0)$. Define $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ in the following way.
$$
f(\lambda)=(1-\lambda,1) ,\lambda\in[0,1/2];\\
f(\lambda)=f(1-1/n)-(\lambda,0), \lambda\in[1-1/n,1-1/(n+1)] \text{ for odd } n;\\
f(\lambda)=f(1-1/n)-(0,\lambda), \lambda\in[1-1/n,1-1/(n+1)] \text{ for even } n;\\
f(2)=(0,0).
$$
It is easy to show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, so it is a path from $(1,1)$ to $(0,0)$. Any two points other that origin are obviously connected by path. So the set is path connected.